# Do I need to purchase a license when I will be creating a website/webapp using mono?

Tags: asp.net, linux, mono, license-key

I used asp.net in a project in an old company. The vs was licensed etc. Right now, I am planning to use mono since my new company is using linux based stuff and I heard that mono uses the .net framework etc. I just want to know if I need to purchase anything or is it ok to create a webapp using mono?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a webapp using mono wihtout buying anything, of course. You only buy from Microsoft the license of Visual Studio, not the .Net compiler nor the Framework.

Comment: more of it, if you find free ide (there some good ones) you don't have to pay anything for creating asp.net under MS .net Framework

Comment: Same applied to WinForm applications.

Comment: Mono also has a certain license (GPL, MIT, LGPL and MSPL for different components) and your company should be aware of the legal consequences (which aren't that dangerous, btw).

Comment: It's not that simple. A lot of .Net is patented by Microsoft. So unless you have a clear statement from Microsoft (as far as I know, Mono developers never got one), that they won't sue you, they can.

Answer (score 0):

@SoMoS has the right answer. If you want more detail, and a better explanation of the patent situation, check out the [Mono Licensing page](http://www.mono-project.com/Licensing).

Comment: thanks for the info. I've read it and has a bit of understanding about it.